# Is a filled in sump pump pit a problem?

Tags: drainage, sump-pump

Filled in sump pump pit an issue? Considering buying new home. Sump pit was filled in at some point with no record of who/why (home is from 2001). Unsure if pit is filled with concrete or other material. Input is appreciated.

Comment: Unless in the desert or high on a hill a pit with a working pump is basic insurance.  I would not use the excuse it has never been needed, since tomorrow it might be needed.  Weather is changing too fast these days.

Answer (score 1):

We have no idea what it's filled with, you'll need to get with the seller/ previous owner.

Sump pumps are usually put in for a reason so I'd be cautious of one being filled in without documentation. Do some investigating, check with the neighbors to see if they have / use sump pumps.

Answer (score 0):

I thought my small sump pit was insurance against the trickle that occasionally found its way past the bulkhead door. I knew the house was in the flood plain (I had to take flood insurance to get the mortgage), but it'd take a hundred-year flood to threaten it

Then we had a hundred-year flood. Groundwater rose to within inches of the surface at the foundation. Under these conditions several other leaks showed up, and adding them all up I was pumping about 8 gallons a minute. (Run pump, drain the one-cubic-foot pit, wait less than a minute, repeat...)

This works much better when there *is* a catch basin. Mist pumps stop a bit above the surface they're placed on, so it helps if that surface is below floor level, even more so if the floor slopes toward it and/or there's a perimeter drain to catch the water as it comes in and route it to the pump.

Having a working simp pit, and a recently tested pump, is cheap insurance. I actually have a spare pump and exhaust hose, insurance on the insurance. And I keep thinking I should put in one of the Venturi backup pumps, which don't need an electrical supply.

Remember that a "hundred-year flood" has about a 1% chance of happening each year. Having had one recently doesn't actually reduce the odds of another happening. And climate change is increasing the frequency and severity of extreme weather events.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Maybe not. Maybe a different problem than the one you expect.

If the basement is reliably dry in all conditions, it's an inconvenient hole in the floor. *I would suggest you remember to run a radon test while still in the pre-purchase phase, though. Might have been a crude and "not the way it's done" attempt at limiting a radon problem?*

If it's full of concrete, reopening it would be difficult. If it's just dirt, a few hours digging would open it back up, if you wanted.

And then there's the really bad one you were not expecting (and it's *probably* unlikely):

> If anyone has gone "mysteriously missing" from the house or area in the past 22 years, you might just have them down that hole - a couple of towns over from mine the wife who "ran off" and "called in from time to time over the years, but only to her husband" was found under a patch in the cellar floor when ground penetrating radar became a thing and the cold case folks at the State Police decided to take a look 20 odd years later (the house had been sold since...)